# Use markitup or masked input plugin (for example) on several elements, created after page loading?

Tags: jquery

Here is a small example with the masked input plugin :

```
//apply the mask to an input
$('.st').live('click', function() {
  $(this).mask("99:99");
});
```

`.st` is a text input with a td, the use can clone the td. However, when you clone this td, and try to click in the `.st` of the new element, your gain the focus of the first `.st` and it's not working.

I have tried several things, `bind()`, `live()`, and `each()` with no results.

Comment: Not 100% sure I've understood this right: `<td><input class="st"></td>`. The user does something which clones `<td>` so that there are two of them, but when they click in the new `.st`, the focus is in the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. New jQuery (since 1.3 or 1.4) can clone everything together with event bindings. See [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) in documentation (supply true as a parameter)
2. You can always write a function binding everything to given elements and take care of it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `$('your_selector').clone(true).appendTo('another_selector').focus()`?